# Issues integrating Kendo into my application

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-map

I have having difficulties getting Kendo UI Map (JavaScript) to work in my application.

I am seeing the containing div load (it has defined width and height). However I only see the map controls appear on in the div and I do not see the map display at all.

I suspect it has something to do with the stylesheets no loading correctly.

I am not getting any javascript errors.

I verified that my kendo.common.min.css and kendo.default.min.css gets loaded before jquery does.

One caveat is that we are bundling our files.  However I am not bundling the kendo css files.  I added a link references on my given page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../Content/Css/Shared/kendocss/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../../Content/Css/Shared/kendocss/kendo.default.min.css" />
```

The other css files that the application use are bundled as well as jquery and all of the javascript files (kendo js files included).

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle of your code? Without seeing your html and how you are loading your javascript files, if any, its hard to figure out.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't the project is too large to break up.